# Dynamically load files to wavesurfer plugin

Tags: javascript, html, wavesurfer.js

Hi I want to load an audio file to display digital signals on browser. I am using wavesurfer.js to display digital signals. Could someone help me to display digital signals for dynamically loaded audio file. How to modify my code to able to read system selected audio and display digital signal for it?

javacript:

```
        input.onchange = function(){
                                    var sound = document.getElementById('sound');
                                    var reader = new FileReader();
                                    reader.onload = function(e) {
                                    sound.src = this.result;
                                    sound.controls = true;
                                    sound.display();
                                    // sound.play(); autoplay feature!!
                                    };
                                    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
                                }
     var buttons = {
                        play: document.getElementById("btn-play"),
                        pause: document.getElementById("btn-pause"),
                        stop: document.getElementById("btn-stop")
                    };

                    // Create an instance of wave surfer with its configuration
                    var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
                        container: '#audio-spectrum',
                        progressColor: "#03a9f4",
                        container: document.querySelector('#audio-spectrum'),
                        backend: 'MediaElement'
                    });

                    // Handle Play button
                    buttons.play.addEventListener("click", function(){
                        wavesurfer.play();

                        // Enable/Disable respectively buttons
                        buttons.stop.disabled = false;
                        buttons.pause.disabled = false;
                        buttons.play.disabled = true;
                    }, false);

 wavesurfer.load('http://ia902606.us.archive.org/35/items/shortpoetry_047_librivox/song_cjrg_teasdale_64kb.mp3');
```

Comment: Use `sound.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])` instead of using the FileReader

Comment: can you please explain How can I load for wavesurfer.load('http://ia902606.us.archive.org/35/items/shortpoetry_047_librivox/song_cjrg_teasdale_64kb.mp3');